# How to make event listener for a React Websocket when it receives a message?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, websocket, network-programming

I'm making a WebSocket client in a .js file using

`this.connection = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8888");`

and setting the onmessage using

`this.connection.onmessage = (e) => { this.receiveData(e.data); };`

A java .jar creates the Websocket Server, and a React website acts as a client. The website acts beautifully with the Websocket, when the server sends to the client it triggers the onmessage. Now I'm trying to send data to the WebSocket from Python (so that it can be displayed on the website), which is a separate client. The onmessage only triggers when the server sends to the website, and not when Python sends to the server. I believe this because of [this discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15919807/11741232)

How can I make the server read the inputs from the Python? All I need is to print the data out for now, because I can handle it from there.

The Python code, getting called in a loop:

```
async def hello():
uri = "ws://localhost:8888"
async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
    d = {
        "type": "test_data",
        "flightData": {
            "latitude": 49.258381363187276,
            "longitude": -123.19507976825994,
            "altitude": 54.4296590927852,
            "velocity": 14.272902869735958,
            "headwind": -0.9}
    }
    data = json.dumps(d)
    await websocket.send(data)
```

Comment: What do you have in function `this.receiveData()` because I don't see any code which can display data on webpage. Maybe you send data correctly from Python but you simply doesn't display it.

Comment: I don't understand `when Python sends to the server.` - `Python` should work as server and it shoud sends to client. And if you run Python as client to send data to server then server would need some code to send this dat to other clients (browsers) because as for me server doesn't know that you want to send something from one client to another.

Comment: @furas I just use console.log in that function, it works for other stuff, no worries there

Comment: @furas Python is acting a client right now, the Java jar is the server. I'll have a look at the server, I didn't write that code but I agree that I need to modify it probably.